# Python won't accept large numbers?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the largest prime factor of a number. Below is my code in Python. When I input 600851475143, it doesn't give me an output. Is this code wrong?

```
def prime(n):
    list = []
    only_primes = []
    for i in range(2,int(n)):
        if n%i==0:
            list.append(i)
            for number in list:
                if isprime(number)==True:
                    only_primes.append(number)
    print(max(only_primes))


def isprime(k):
    for z in range(2,int(k**1/2)+1):
        if k%z==0:
            return False
    return True

print(prime(600851475143))
```

Comment: It just runs like forever?

Comment: Add some print function calls to monitor your code execution and you will see it just works. _won't accept large numbers_ is incorrect, especially when it comes to number like 600851475143 that is not that big at all. Also, don't use `list` as name,

Comment: From a quick skim, this seems to be *O(`n`^3)*, so it makes sense that it runs incredibly slow for large numbers. The real killer is `for number in list`, which doesn't seem necessary; `isprime(i)` seems to make sense.

Answer (score 3):

**There are a couple things wrong here.**

1. Most notably, the indentation on your 2nd `for` loop is off which is causing that loop to be ran every single iteration of the first `for` loop. It should be at the same indentation as the first so it can run strictly after.
2. Your algorithm is still far too slow to compute the largest prime factor of the number 600,851,475,143. It will only run in a feasible amount of time for numbers in the millions range. If you would like to run computations for numbers of that size, you will have to use a more advanced technique.
3. You are missing parentheses for the exponent in `isprime`'s `for` loop.
4. In the case that your input number happens to be prime, your code will crash due to the `only_primes` list being empty.

Here is a fixed version:

```
   def prime(n):
        list = []
        only_primes = []
    
        for i in range(2, int(n)):
            if n % i == 0:
                list.append(i)
    
        for number in list:
            if isprime(number):
                only_primes.append(number)
    
        if len(only_primes) > 0:
            return max(only_primes)
    
        return n
    
    def isprime(k):
        for z in range(2, int(k**(1/2) + 1)):
            if k % z == 0:
                return False
        return True
    
    print(prime(1001))
```